# wix service doesn't start, but if i start manually, it works

Tags: .net, windows-services, wix, windows-installer

I am writing an installer using wix. As part of installation, i am installing a service and starting it. But I am unable to start the service.

This is the wix code:

```
      <Component Id="Service" Guid="*">
    <File Id="MyService.exe"
          Name="MyService.exe"
          Source="MyService.exe"/>

    <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                    Type="ownProcess"
                    Vital="yes"
                    Name="MyService"
                    DisplayName="Name="MyService.exe"
                    Description="Name="MyService.exe"
                    Start="auto"
                    Account="LocalSystem"
                    ErrorControl="normal"
                    Interactive="no">

      <ServiceDependency Id="CcmExec"/>
    </ServiceInstall>

    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceController"
                    Start="install"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="uninstall"
                    Name="MyService"
                    Wait="no"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

After going through the msi verbose logs it says error 1920

But if I install the service manually (using MyService -service from cmd prompt) and start it using Services.msc, it works fine. After that my installer is able to uninstall and again upon reinstalling able to start the service without any issues.

Answer (score 6):

The Name attribute of your ServiceControl element isn't matching the Name attribute of your ServiceInstall element.   You are creating a service called "MyService" but trying to start a service named "MyService.exe".  This service doesn't exist so you get a 1920.

Also a secondary cause could be that your service exe has COM metadata and you haven't authored this into the wxs.

Comment: Of course this is a heavily redacted snippet of wxs source so it may be impossible to ever truely help you.

Comment: The name is the same. I am sorry that while pasting the code here the typo got introduced.

Comment: please let me know if i can add anything more here that can help me resolve the issue.

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without doing indepth profiling, logging and troubleshooting of the installer on a clean VM. Your source example is redacted to the point of not being relevant to the question. If you want a wild ass guess, I'd say make sure you are harvesting and authoring the COM metadata for this EXE into your WXS file.  I don't see any evidence of it in your sample.